# Is there a way to determine part of speech patterns in a dataset of sentences?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have a pandas dataframe with sentences and I'd like to determine part of speech patterns in each sentence. What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most popular POS taggers for Python are NLTK and spaCy. [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) is both faster and easier to use, and as you need to do more, spaCy also provides a nice API for interacting with wordnet, word Vectors, and other more advanced tools.

This is how you do POS reading with spaCy:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
doc = nlp(u'Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion')

for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.pos_, token.tag_, token.dep_,
            token.shape_, token.is_alpha, token.is_stop)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple approach that might help you. 
Take a list of n-grams generated from your sentences. The ones that occur the maximum number of times can be the patterns identified.